# create case from bcc email

Tags: salesforce-id, email2case

Is it posible to create case from bcc email address ?
When mail send to the email service address copied in BCC , it need to create case in salesforce. Can any one suggest me is it posible ? Please provide the steps for understanding.

Thanks,
Anjana

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to read the BCC email address unless exchange team did scripting from exchange server to be able to get BCC in email headers.

Here is the article that could help you similar to your requirement.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_inbound_email.htm&type=0

http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/retrieving-information-from-incoming-email-messages